# ImportError: No module named PyQt4 on my Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, pyqt4

I've got PyQt4 and pyqt4-dev-tools installed on my raspberry pi but I'm getting

> ImportError: No module named PyQt4 on my Raspberry Pi

with the following includes when I run python3

> from PyQt4 import QtGui
>
> from PyQt4 import QtCore

I've got another Pi that PyQT4 is found so I'm not sure what I've done wrong on this one.  Can anyone tell me what I can do to get Python to find the PyQt4 modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you installed `PyQt4` and `pyqt4-dev-tools` for Python 2.x, but not for Python 3.x.

Check if `PyQt4` is in your `site-packages` directory for Python 3.x. For me this is under `/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PyQt4`.

If it's not there, you need to grab the correct Python 3 version of the packages. What distro are you using?

Comment: Thanks for you help - I'm using Python 3.2 on Debian (Raspbian) (not sure how to get 3.4) but my path is /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt4. Is this in the correct spot? @jashanddeep-sohi

Comment: You can find out by looking in the `sys.path` variable in Python. It lists all the paths Python searches for modules. -- So does `PyQt4` exists under `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/`? Try `import PyQt4` in both the `python2` and `python3` interpreter , and see if any works. Also make sure you are running the script with the correct version (i.e. `python2 my_script.py` vs `python3 my_script.py`)

Comment: Where can I find the sys.path - I can't find it anywhere?  PyQt4 does exist under dist-packages.  Import PyQt4 does work but I loose the QtGui parts of my program but the QtCore still works (is that what you meant by "import PyQt4...interpreter")?  @jashanddeep-sohi

Comment: `sys.path` is in the `sys` module. You must first `import sys`. What I mean by starting the interpreter is, typing  `python` on the command line. From there you can test if the needed module imports. Please edit your question with the **actual** errors that you see. Also is this a script you are running and how are you running it?